# Multiple templates of a class in the same function

Tags: c++

I'm getting an error related to using the same class but with different types int and char

```
template <typename ItemType>
int Infix::performOp(LinkedStack<ItemType> valueStack, LinkedStack<ItemType> operatorStack)
```

valueStack is the int, and operatorStack the char.

When I compile this is the note it attaches to the error.

```
template argument deduction/substitution failed:
```

followed by this note

```
deduced conflicting types for parameter ‘ItemType’ (‘int’ and ‘char’)
```

Is having multiple types of the same class possible in the same function definition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use

```
template <typename ItemType>
int Infix::performOp(LinkedStack<ItemType> valueStack,
                     LinkedStack<ItemType> operatorStack) { ... }
```

both `valueStack` and `operatorStack` have to be of the same type.

Unless `operatorStack` can be of a type different than `LinkedStack<char>`, you can use:

```
template <typename ItemType>
int Infix::performOp(LinkedStack<ItemType> valueStack,
                     LinkedStack<char> operatorStack) { ... }
```

Unless your function needs to make changes to the arguments, I would suggest making the arguments `const&`.

```
template <typename ItemType>
int Infix::performOp(LinkedStack<ItemType> const& valueStack,
                     LinkedStack<char> const& operatorStack) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't have a *specific* `template` argument work as more than one type in an invocation; think of like like trying to use the same function argument for multiple values in the same situation.

The solution is to use multiple `template` arguments:

```
template <typename ItemType1, typename ItemType2>
int Infix::performOp(LinkedStack<ItemType1> valueStack,
                     LinkedStack<ItemType2> operatorStack)
```